# java.net.SocketException: Connection reset at Jmeter

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing

I'm doing a  load test on a web application, and with minimum of 14-15 users am getting this connection reset issue and I ensure the following from my end:

1. Request retries has been set to 1 in user.properties files
2. stale check is set to true
3. Test data and lan connectivity is good.
4. number of users are less hence it wont need more RAM for jmeter

Hence could this be concluded as an issue in application design and not an issue from Jmeter?

Comment: What is max. no. of connections on app. server. Try doing it manually with similar no. of users if you get similar error then app side issue else it is from JMeter. Check server logs and JMeter logs for possible causes

Comment: I conducted a test with 20 users with user ramp up of 60 seconds, and all the threads are getting passed. But when a 20 users hit the system with a user ramp up time of 20 seconds, then around 2-3 transaction fail. Hence does it not mean app server is not able to take more concurrent Logins?

Comment: yes. This clearly shows app server is not capable of taking that many concurrent login connections.

Comment: Thank you, seems to be same; because on looking the logs on application server the failure is due to the unique key not updated for the session id in DB for those failed users. Is there any fix available for this?

Answer (score 0):

To avoid long trail of comments, I'll try to summarize it and answer.

This issue looks from application deployment system.

```
JMeter ---------------> ( Web server <-> App server <-> DB )
```

Find out in which area bottleneck is present using profilers.

Issue could be in anyone of below layers,

1. **Web Server** : 
   If Web server is bottleneck then try to tune the web server for handling more load. Like more threadpool size, more timeouts, buffers, queues
2. **Application Server** :
   If app server is bottleneck then tune your application server. Again check configurations, any specific settings for handling more load and if required code improvement should be done.
3. **Database Server** : 
   If DB is bottleneck then check queries, indexes, statistics and optimize them for your needs. config settings also help sometimes.

For all layers check server resource utilization. If it is not much then there is room for perf. improvement else server vertical/horizontal scaling is required.

You are saying problem is because some ids were not generated in DB. so you can start with DB layer for possible bottlenecks.

Hope this helps :)